# Dynamic url in jQuery UI , data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, datatables

I have a jQuery application which performs a get request and populates the jQuery data table.

The url (whole url) will be passed by the client application and I am required to read the url and process the same i.e. making a jQuery.get() request and populating the data table. The data table is in a jquery ui dialog.

The client will click on a button and it'll open the UI dialog box which contains the data table, the url will be passed by the button.

I want to catch the url in js and pass it in AJAX request like in the code below.

thanks in advance.

here is my code :-

```
$(document).ready(function() {



                    $("#notesDialog").dialog({
                        autoOpen : false,
                        title : "Notes",
                        hide : "",
                        width : 'auto',
                        height : 'auto',
                        modal : true
                    });


                    var table = $('#notesTable').dataTable({

                            bJQueryUI : true,
                            "processing" : true,
                            "serverSide" : true,
                            "contentType" : "application/json",
                            "dataType" : "jsonp",
                            "bStateSave" : false,
                            "bAutoWidth" : false,
                            "sAjaxSource" : "url",
                            "sAjaxDataProp" : '',
                            "crossDomain" : true,
                            "aoColumns" : [
                                    {
                                        "mData" : "onBoarded",
                                        "sWidth" : "20%",
                                        "mRender" : function(data,type, full) {
                                        var newStr = new Date(data).toUTCString();
                                        var str = newStr.substring(0,newStr.length - 3);
                                        return str.substring(4);

                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "mData" : "createdBy"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "mData" : "comment",
                                        "mRender" : function(data,type, full) {
                                        var showChar = 50;
                                        var ellipsestext = "...";
                                        var moretext = "more";
                                        var lesstext = "less";
                                        var contentt = JSON.stringify(data);
                                        var content = contentt.replace(/["]+/g,'').substring(1,contentt.length - 1);

                                        if (content.length > showChar) {

                                            var c = content.substr(0,showChar);
                                            var h = content.substr(showChar - 1,content.length- showChar);

                                            var html = c
                                                    + '<span class="moreellipses">'
                                                    + ellipsestext
                                                    + '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>'
                                                    + h
                                                    + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">'
                                                    + moretext
                                                    + '</a></span>';

                                            return html.toString();
                                        }

                                        $(".morelink").click(function() {
                                                    if ($(this).hasClass("less")) {
                                                                $(this).removeClass("less");
                                                                $(this).html(moretext);
                                                            } else {
                                                                $(this).addClass("less");
                                                                $(this).html(lesstext);
                                                            }
                                                            $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
                                                            $(this).prev().toggle();
                                                            return false;
                                                        });

                                        return data;
                                    }
                                }, {
                                    "mData" : "tag"
                                } ]

                    });



    $("#opener").click(function() {
    $("#notesDialog").dialog("open");

    $('#notesDialog').dialog("widget").position({

        });
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to get your current url ?

then you can use

```
window.location.href
```

to get current url of your window.

Comment: "sAjaxSource" : window.location.href --- like this ?

Comment: actually the url is passed by the client , could be anything ,  not the window url of the current page.

Comment: are you using asp.net or mvc ?